# Pidgin script with Python/ Get Focus Signal

Tags: python, plugins, ubuntu-12.04, dbus, pidgin

I am creating a script in Python to integrate Pidgin with Unity (Ubuntu 12.04), I've managed to do the counting notifications system using the Unity API, but i dont know what event or signal that is activated when the conversation window gains focus(To clear the message counter)... 
I've tried some of the signals available on the documentation of Pidgin (https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto) but none of them worked, is there any GTK(or anything) event that is triggered when the window chat gets focus?

Comment: All of Pidgin's DBus signals can be found [here](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/conversation-signals.html#receiving-chat-msg). It doesn't look like there's a signal for that event.

Comment: I've tried to use some of them but they end up overwriting the signal "received-im-msg" used to update the counter... So when I add, they end up wiping the counter instantly

Answer (score 0):

Conversation UI signals are listed [here](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/gtkconv-signals.html) those might be more helpful for what you are trying to do.

Though I don't know that I understand what you meant by your comment about the counter being wiped instantly when you tried some of the other signals. That sounds like it might be a coding error to me.